# Registers working

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I hope i am not making this question out of scope , i am a programmer guy and i always do consult with this site whenever i am stucked
so The question is that i don't know about registers and how they work i only know one thing that registers are small amount of memory inside cpu 
but i want to know more how like how to convert a registers value from assembly to hex this seems knida noob but i hav'nt learnt this thing
if i have an assembly like this

```
mov dl,oah
mov ah,oaah
mov bh,0010b
```

know here some stuff is being moved to  dl,ah,and bh i just want to know how to calculate there address and hex values is there any table which i can use to find out this or a good way to calculate this

Comment: 0010b is binary value 0010 (see the trailing b char), the decimal value is 2. The values ending with 'h' are hex values. I think oah is in fact 0ah (0A hex, 10 decimal) and oaah is 0aah (0AA hex, 170 decimal).

Comment: artemix thanks for ur reply sir , i know all this but i want to know is to how to find out the hex value for the registers where these values are going to b saved and what is the memory address for each register

Comment: Registers do not have memory addresses. Memory is "outside" of processor, while the registers are "inside" of processor. You can reference the registers by names like AX, BX, CX, etc., you can write or read values from "lower" or "higher" parts of the register (AH, AL, EAX), but they are not stored in memory and therefore they do not have memory addresses.

Comment: artemix , thank you for pointing this out now correct me if i am wrong does mov dl,oah means content of dl will be moved to a memory location of hex value a?

Comment: No, `mov dl, 0Ah` is equal to `dl = 0Ah`. Read [Wikipedia on mov instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_(x86_instruction))

Comment: ok thank you sir , enough for me i will do find things my self now thanks for giving me right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to think of registers is as storage on the CPU.  Different processors have different numbers and types of registers. Registers typically are the width of the processor.  So a 32 bit processor will have mostly 32 bit wide registers.  Registers can be loaded with absolute values, or with memory addresses.  The disassembler or debugger that you use to list assembly instructions will show what is happening.  The assembler codes will most often show values in hexadecimal, but other formats are possible.  It depends on your CPU/debugger/disassembler.  You should look for some assembly language tutorials for the CPU you are interested in.

Comment: ok this is something what i want , infact i want to code a simple appication in vb.net that can find the memory address if i put assembly code like mov ah,0ah it should give me the address of memory where it is going

Comment: If you want to learn the instruction set, then find the assembly language reference manual for the CPU that you are interested in.  You can then go through all of the addressing modes of the different instructions.  If you are interested in actual values from real programs, use a debugger like Windbg.

Answer (score 0):

Registers themselves generally do not have an address, they are normally not accessible through the memory space.  There are a few processors where this was actually the case but that is the exception not the rule.

The slight notion of an address that a register has is the value used in the machine code.  You have chosen here to use x86 which doesnt necessarily follow that notion but if you look at something like arm or mips or a number of others, it is a lot more obvious. r0 will have a bit pattern of 0b0000, r1 0b0001, r2 0b0010 and so on in the machine code in the instruction itself.  And there is likely a ram in the guts of the processor that may use these register bits modified or not, but that ram is not accessible in any other way to the programmer than as a place where register contents are held.

For any processor go to the processor vendors website or do some googling for the instruction set for that processor.  the vendor docs usually include an opcode map or basically the machine code for each instruction, per instruction.  Some non-vendor websites may only have the syntax as a programmers reference and not the machine code, so those wont help you.  The one or few processors whose registers are memory mapped will also have documentation (the one I am thinking of is old enough though that you might not find the original vendor documentation).